# Form submit is not working in Safari browser?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, safari

I have a **dropdown** where after selecting option it will submit and post the value using **jQuery & PHP**, **my code is working fine in chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE but not working in safari**.

**HTML**

```
<form action="New1.php" method="post" style="margin:0;" id="fonts" >
 <div style="margin-right:15px;" id= "select"> 
   <select class="selectpicker rounded" id= "select" name="select" method="post" onchange="findmyvalue()"  style="font-size:16px; padding:2px 29px 2px 3px; border:1px solid #929292!important; max-width:250px;" data-live-search="true" data-width="5%">
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </select>  
  </div>  
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
function findmyvalue()
{
  var myval = document.getElementById("fonts").value;

  $( "#fonts" ).click(function findmyvalue() {
    $( "#fonts" ).submit();
  });
}
```

How can I fix this, or any better way that works in all browsers ?

Comment: The `findmyvalue()` function is never called, why mention it here?

Comment: typo error my bad, I have updated my code with `onchange="findmyvalue()"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what exactly the precise root cause is to be honest - you didn't mention any error messages or any other description of the precise behaviour, but I suspect it simply never calls your "findmyvalue" function at all. Overall though the code is a bit of a mess for various reasons.

Primarily, if you want to submit the form when someone selects an option in the dropdown, then the appropriate thing is to handle the "change" event of the dropdown.

e.g.

HTML:

```
<form action="New1.php" method="post" style="margin:0;" id="fonts" >
 <div style="margin-right:15px;"> 
    <select class="selectpicker rounded" id= "select" name="select" style="font-size:16px; padding:2px 29px 2px 3px; border:1px solid #929292!important; max-width:250px;" data-live-search="true" data-width="5%">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
   </select>
  </div>  
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#select").change(function() {
  $("#fonts").submit();
});
```

I would be surprised if this more standard approach doesn't work correctly.

Comment: ` Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' ` in your jQuery

Comment: Sorry just missed the brackets off the "function". See correction above.